# Read text file from mobile device using python

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to read the content of log file from phone's internal storage using python, but I am unable to locate the file as the phone connects as a device instead of drive.

Mentioned is the script I'm trying.

```
f = open("This PC\\MotoE2(4G-LTE)\\Internal storage\\Logger\\main.log", "rt")
content = f.read()
list = ["SettingConfigUtils: MCC: 404/ MNC: 45", "SettingConfigUtils: isPolandP4P_SIM", "SettingConfigUtils: MCC: 404/ MNC: 45", "TelephonyManager: getDataEnabled: retVal=true"]
for var in list:
    toFind = var
    length = len(toFind)
    ret_val = content.find(toFind)
    if ret_val != -1:
        end = ret_val + length
        print (content[ret_val:end] +": Found")
    else:
        print (var +": Not Found")
    #break
f.close()
```

Error Message:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'This PC\MotoE2(4G-LTE)\Internal storage\Logger\main.log'

Comment: see if you change directory to `This PC\MotoE2(4G-LTE)\Internal storage\Logger\ `  this path from your cmd or terminal(if using from linux) before you can conclude the the issue is because you are `unable to locate the file as the phone connects as a device instead of drive`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, tried changing directory, no luck.
C:\>cd /d This PC:\MotoE2(4G-LTE)\Internal storage\ The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.